# how to identify on command line terminal emulator apps and packages that have active network connections

Tags: root-access, malware, magisk, firewall, termux

I tried this using an app and I am able to identify most apps and their  `network connections` however there are certain apps listed as  `'?'` so apparently it is not able to identify a `package` name I would like to know how I can get this information on `command line` using `termux` or any other `emulator`. I am `magisk`aly  `root`ed on an `Android 10`   phone

also would like to get a list of apps that can modify contacts and then revoke modification of contacts from certain apps by command line

and on `command line` how do I force `kill` an `app` I mean I can use the `hang -9 Signal` ....but I am sure there must be a more gentle `package-`level way of force stopping an app title the equivalent of getting inside the app property on `gui` and clicking that `force stop` button

also delete the `cache` on `command line`

what I want to do is write a `batch` script that will overwrite certain app specific files that the app keeps resetting every time and then force stop and clear `cache` and restart the app

Answer (score 2):

- If you mean by `network connection` the applications that has "android.permission.INTERNET" permission, then run this shell script:

```
for package in $(pm list packages -3 | cut -f2 -d":"); do
dumpsys package $package | grep "android.permission.INTERNET: granted=true" > /dev/null && echo $package
done;
```

- If you want to list all applications that are connected to internet:

```
netstat -tuplna
```

That will list all application that has an established connection

- If you want for each App an their mobile data usage:

```
for package in $(pm list packages | cut -f2 -d":"); do echo $package; pm dump $package | grep  "Mobile network"; done;
```

- To kill an App:

```
am force-stop PACKAGE_NAME
```

- Clear cache:

```
pm clear PACKAGE_NAME
```

Comment: Good Morning  thanks for responding I actually extended the question with some other related subs as well if you have a chance to respond to those .....will then gladly ✅ this off.